# Pattern matching multiple elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

If I had for example a list of types:

```
[Circle r, Square s, Rectangle w d, Equil.Triangle t, Circle r, Rectangle wd]
```

I want to swap two elements of the same type in a list.
I tried for example pattern matching like:

```
swap (Circle r1:y:Circle r2:xs) = (Circle r2:y:Circle r1:xs)
```

Is there any way to match one or more elements with *y* or is there another preferred method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But `y` here is *an* element of the list, regardless of the data constructor.

Comment: I just wanna get this out there: by definition, if they're all in the same list, then they're all of the same type.  What you're doing is matching on different data constructors for the same type.

Comment: After rereading the question, I have the idea that with `y`, you want to specify zero or more elements of the list. This is impossible, since Haskell actually has no special understanding of lists (at least not syntactically), it only looks at the data constructors.

Comment: You can't use pattern matching to skip over an arbitrary portion of a list. You can pattern match on `Circle r1 : rest` and then scan over `rest` trying to find another circle. For that you can define a custom recursive function taking `rest` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html) package, using `Circle`s as delimiters. There are two interesting cases: either the list begins with a `Circle`, in which case the first two delimiters will be at the start of the first two lists in the split, or the list does not begin with a `Circle`, in which case the first two delimiters will be at the start of the second and third elements in the split.

```
import Data.List.Split

isCircle (Circle _) = True
isCircle _ = False

swap shapes = case split (keepDelimsL $ whenElt isCircle) shapes of
    (c@(Circle _):ss):(c':ss'):sss -> concat $ (c':ss):(c:ss):sss
    ss:(c:ss'):(c':ss''):sss -> concat $ ss:(c':ss'):(c:ss''):sss
    _ -> shapes -- what if there aren't two circles?
```

Comment: Hm. After rereading the question... whether I would do this or not depends a bit on what exactly you are meaning to do. This is what I would do if I wanted to swap the first two circles. If I wanted to swap the first element with the next element that had the same constructor, I'd do something different (though similar).

Answer (score 2):

Per Daniel Wagner's comment on his answer:

> If I wanted to swap the first element with the next element that had the same constructor, I'd do something different

I thought I'd answer that question too, since the posted question is ambiguous in this regard. I'd write a function that tests equality by constructor, e.g.:

```
-- from your code somewhere, however this is defined
data Shape a = Circle a
             | Square a
             | Rectangle a a
             | EquilTriangle a

sameShape :: Shape a -> Shape a -> Bool
sameShape (Circle _) (Circle _)               = True
sameShape (Square _) (Square _)               = True
sameShape (Rectangle _ _) (Rectangle _ _)     = True
sameShape (EquilTriangle _) (EquilTriangle _) = True
sameShape _ _                                 = False
```

then pull out the head of the list as `x`, `break` on `sameShape x`, and reassemble the list from there.

```
swapHeadWithSameConstructor :: [Shape a] -> [Shape a]
swapHeadWithSameConstructor xss@(x:xs) =
  let (xs', ys) = break (sameShape x) xs
  in  case ys of
        (y:ys') -> y : xs' ++ x : ys'
        []      -> xss  -- if there's no element to swap, change nothing
```